# Is $U$ a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$U=\{(2r,-s^2,t) \mid r, s\ \text{ and}\ t \ \in \Bbb R\}$

So I know I have to make sure of the following:

(a) The zero vector is in $U$ (replace $r,s,t$ by $0$ and you get $0$)

(b) It is closed under addition (the resultant of adding other vectors, like $(r,s,t)$ to $(2r,-s^2,t)$, is still in $U$)

(c) It is closed under scalar multiplication (any scalar times $U$ is still in $U$)

I found that they all work. But apparently, $U$ is not a subset. Why? Is it because there are three variables, $r,s,t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1,-1,1)$ is in $U$. Multiply by $-1$, which is a scalar. The vector $(-1,1,-1)$ is not in $U$. (Notice $-s^2$ can only be a negative number. In my experience such condition is a red flag!!)

Comment: But what's wrong with $-s^2$ only being a negative number when the condition on $s$ is that it must be in R?

Comment: As you pointed out, a subspace must be closed under scalar multiplication. If one entry of a vector inside a subset of interest can only be a negative number, multiplying it by a negative number would give us a vector outside that set (because the negative entry now becomes positive,) making the subset not closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Similar example: consider our usual xy-plane. The first quadrant is not a subspace of $R^2$, because multiply any nonzero vector inside the first quadrant by a negative number and the multiplied vector is outside the first quadrant.

Comment: Ohhh thank you so much for the added explanation!!